# Shh connection, in a Jenkins pipeline, disconnects after login

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, ssh

Scenario: I'm developing a jenkins step that needs to transfer a file to a machine (install a jboss module). I'm trying to do it via ssh interactions. I need to connect via ssh, switch to an authorized user in order to access jboss folders/files, and then use rsync to transfer the jar file inside jboss modules folder. I cannot use the same user to ssh and jboss.

Problem: I can successfully connect via ssh, but when I send the first command (to switch user), it disconnects and then nothing works anymore. Appearently is disconnecting before the 'su' command is executed. The next command would be to check if module folder exists (and create it if doesn't).

The sequence of commands is executed inside a function:

```
def installModule(HOST, USER, PASSWORD) {
    sh set -x && sshpass -p [PASSWORD] ssh -v -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no [USER]@[HOST] echo [PASSWORD] | sudo -S su - jboss && cd [MODULE_FOLDER] && if [[ ! -e [MODULE_VERSION] ]]; then mkdir [MODULE_VERSION]; fi
}
```

The console output:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to [MACHINE_NAME_HERE] ([IP_HERE]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: tty_make_modes: no fd or tio
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: echo [PASSWORD_HERE]
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 2 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Connection to [MACHINE_NAME_HERE] closed.
Transferred: sent 2180, received 3356 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 7006.2, received 10785.6
debug1: Exit status 0
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for jenkins: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for jenkins:
sudo: no password was provided
sudo: 2 incorrect password attempts
```

Any help would be appreciated =)

Comment: why all shell commands quoted? what is the real jenkins code?

Comment: @daggett the commands are being stored in variables (strings), hence the quotes. The jenkins code is sh "${commandsInterpolated}"

Comment: If you still need help, please edit your question and provide code that executes your shell. Problem is there. `"${commandsInterpolated}"` doesn't provide an answer how your strings converted to `"${commandsInterpolated}"`

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar, in my case, I opt for having a shell script file in  my environment containing all the commands I needed to be executed on the remote machine.

I did it like this:

```
withCredentials([
  usernamePassword(credentialsId: "$VM_CREDENTIALS", usernameVariable: 'USER_VM', passwordVariable: 'PWD_VM')
]) {
   script {
      sh 'sshpass -p $PWD_VM ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER_VM@$IP_VM "bash -s ' + "$VARIABLE_A $VARIABLE_B" + '" < path/to/shell/script.sh'
   }
}
```

I used `$VARIABLE_A` and `$VARIABLE_B` to pass some arguments to the script. The `$path/to/shell_script.sh` represents the path to the script placed in your Jenkins environment to be executed on the remote machine.

I also had to switch users in the shell script, I did it like so:

```
# Switch to root user
echo $PWD | sudo -S sleep 1 && sudo -E su
```

Remember, don't define the `$PWD` variable **hardcoded somewhere**, you need to take security measures.

Comment: Thanks for you answer sir, but could you show how did the commands followed the su? Here it seems to switch the user but immediatelly switch back and everything goes wrong aka i'm not being able to execute commands in the behalf of the new user

Comment: After that command I just start executing the commands for the new user. Try to create a new directory after that command using `mkdir ./myDir` to check in what user is being created. Keep in mind I'm switching to the root user, the PWD I provide is for the root